# Stress test for heroku free server

Tags: android, selenium, heroku, django-rest-framework, stress-testing

I am developing an Android app with backend of heroku free server. Now it is taking 2 seconds to serve a request. so, how much user it can serve at a time.

I have seen many quora questions and about stress test tools. But, I didn't really get that info. So, please help me on this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is a very powerful tool for stress/load testing. You can simulate any specified number of users that will be hitting your services. 
Check out this tutorial here...
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-jmeter-to-perform-load-testing-on-a-web-server